# what do selected vertex colors mean?

Tags: interface

[image]

When I selected a vertex by clicking left mouse button on it,and selected vertex looked white. 
And then for some reason I selected the vertex by dragging left mouse button around it, then selected vertex looked orange.
I wonder why vertex colors are different in each case and  what each color means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white vertex is the active selection, and the orange vertex is not active.

Comment: thank you for answer

Comment: Sure! It's actually a feature, because you can use the active selection as your pivot point, your center for snapping, lots of stuff. For example, when you rig a model, select a bone, then another bone, and press shift-ctrl-C. Blender will create a constraint on the active bone targeted to the selected bone. You can also use this feature to parent selected object to active. Something I often do is copy/link data from active to selected.